# How to buy everything with bitcoins

Tags: transactions, payment

Is there a place, where i can buy everything in other countries and pay with bitcoins?

I know there is a place somewhere.

Comment: It might be good idea to mention [Proxy Coins](http://www.proxycoins.com/)

Comment: :) I love this question

Answer (score 2):

[Snapcard](http://joinsnapcard.com) is a buying service that uses a bookmarklet to populate a shopping cart on Snapcard's site using product details from the e-commerce site you want to buy from.   Coindesk's [writeup](http://www.coindesk.com/snapcard-merchants-shop-bitcoin) on the service gives more info.

[Edited: This comment originally was for BitSpend.net which is now defunct.]

Comment: BitSpend.net is closed, what about the alternative https://all4btc.com/ ?

Comment: @rubo77: The way I understand your question, your comment would be a valid answer.

Answer (score 0):

I recently heard of http://bitcoinstore.com

They don't provide "everything", and I'm not sure how shipping works, but they have quite a large selection. The way I understand that it works is they take in bitcoin, convert it to dollars, and then pay the actual provider of the item(NewEgg, Amazon, etc)

Comment: -1 for incorrect information.  Bitcoinstore.com is a great site, but it's not a pass through site that pays Amazon or NewEgg to provide items.  They are themselves an electronics store that stock items they source from manufacturers.  See their official blog at http://bitcoinstore.tumblr.com/ for more details.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use OKPAY they accept bitcoins to fund your wallet at a "market rate" and then you get credited Cash in your wallet.

They also have the ability to create a virtual master card which i thought is pretty cool, so you can essentially use it online.

Although you do need to be verified to use their services.

Note: At the time of writing this, the market rate was $30 cheaper USD per coin compared to BTC-e (normally one of the lower values) , but depending on how badly you want to spend it everywhere, its not bad.

Answer (score 0):

Right now the it's still hard to buy everything using bitcoin, but you can use bitcoin to buy gift cards from [gyft](http://www.gyft.com) and use it at many places.